# ListView Control add multiple records

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Is this is possible to make list view empty with textbox and dropdownlist also with eight header and 10 rows with textbox and dropdownlist and when click on button all row one by one data save in database using ajax...
[image]

i try this:-

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server">

   <LayoutTemplate>
      <table class="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" rules="rows">
         <tr class="headerRow">
            <th style="width:40px;"></th>
            <th style="width:40px;">ID</th>
            <th style="width:230px;">Name</th>
            <th style="width:230px;">Fee</th>
         </tr>
         <tbody>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </LayoutTemplate>

   <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <img id="btnEdit" style="cursor: pointer;" alt="Edit" src="images/edit.png" 
                 />                    
         </td>
         <td>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("Code") %>'></asp:TextBox>

         </td>
         <td>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("BRCode")%>'></asp:TextBox>

         </td>
         <td>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:TextBox>

         </td>
      </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
          <EmptyDataTemplate>
             <table class="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" rules="rows">
         <tr class="headerRow">
            <th style="width:40px;"></th>
            <th style="width:40px;">ID</th>
            <th style="width:230px;">Name</th>
            <th style="width:230px;">Fee</th>
         </tr>

                 <tr>
         <td>
            <img id="btnEdit" style="cursor: pointer;" alt="Edit" src="images/edit.png" 
                 />                    
         </td>
         <td>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>

         </td>
         <td>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>

         </td>
         <td>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>

         </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>      
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: how..please provide one example..

Comment: originally default i need list view is empty.but as listview when data is available then listview is not empty,hence editdatatemplate is not works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a ListView with 10 rows. Create a dummy list and DataBind it to the ListView.

```
        List<int> myList = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            myList.Add(i);
        }
        ListView1.DataSource = myList;
        ListView1.DataBind();
```